# What is the minimum value of $(\sin x + \cos x + \csc (2x))^3$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the minimum value of:

$$(\sin x + \cos x + \csc 2x )^3$$

let us consider that  $0<x<\pi/2$

Use of differentiation is not allowed.!

Now we can use am gm  to get the minimum value as 13.5...!!But the problem is that for this to holds $\sin x = \cos x = \csc(2x)$ which is not possible..

Comment: Is $\sec$ bounded from below? Are $\sin$ and $\cos$ bounded from above?

Comment: i had solved it withh differentiation...but not by any other method.!!

Comment: @mathslover What are your views on my question?

Comment: bounded on what?

Comment: @mathslover "bounded". I mean that do $\sin$  and $\cos$ have maximum values? Does $\sec$ have a minimum value?

Comment: Is wolfram alpha allowed?

Comment: Is there a value of $x$ for which $sine$, $cosine$ or $secant$ not defined ?

Answer (score 3):

As
$$lim_{x\to\frac\pi4^+}\sec 2x=-\infty$$
$\sin x+\cos x$ is bounded and $t\mapsto t^3$ is increasing, there is no minimum in $(0,\pi/2)$.

But in the interval $[0,\pi/4)$:
$$\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt 2 \sin(x+\pi/4)$$
is increasing and $\sec 2x\ $ is also increasing, so their sum composed with the cube is increasing. Because this, the minimum is reached at $x=0$:
$$(\sin 0+\cos x+\sec 0)^3=2^3=8.$$

Comment: can u tell at which value is this attained

Comment: Point 0, value 8.

Comment: see 0 is not allowed in domain

Comment: Then there is not minimum. The *infimum* is 8.

Comment: sry there was and editing error..it was cosec not sec..!!